# How to extract a few APIs from one OpenAPI doc to another?

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

My application generates a JSON/YAML for all the API endpoints. However, I have an API gateway where I only allow a subset of these. For this, I currently pick the APIs manually from the first doc along with its models and create a new doc that can be supplied to the API Gateway.

This manual process takes a lot of time and is too complex when it comes to nested model schemas.

Is there a way I can automate this process so that a path I choose can be extracted out with its models to a new Open API doc.

Comment: Check out [openapi-filter](https://github.com/Mermade/openapi-filter), I think it can do what you need

Comment: @Helen Tried `npx openapi-filter -i -- source.yaml target.yaml` but it only copies the path, not its associated definitions.

Comment: I think I just needed a `--valid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `openapi-filter`.
https://github.com/Mermade/openapi-filter

Mark the APIs with `x-internal: true` as shown below:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: API
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /:
    get:
      x-internal: true
      ...
```

Run the following command (where `source.yaml` is your input file):

```
npx openapi-filter --inverse --valid --strip -- source.yaml target.yaml
```

**Explanation**:

```
--inverse: to include the APIs marked (and not exclude them, which is the default filter).
--valid: to copy all the other associated objects (and not just the paths)
--strip: to remove the flags added manually
```

**Compatibility**:

> Works with OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 and 3.0.x and AsyncAPI definitions.

Credits to @Helen

Comment: `--inverse` is not working (just creates invalid swagger)
models are not filtered. totally useless. can be done with one regexp